# QGIS export to 3d mesh format

Tags: qgis, delaunay

I'm testing qgis triangulation. So far I managed to extract a single polyogon, simplify it, and convert to points.
The problem is that the triangulation produces something unexpected.

This is the points
[image: points]

And this is after the triangulator.
[image: triangulate]

My expectation was that the process could reproduce the shape of the country.
My overall objective is to export the shapefile to a 3d program, since I don't see export options to 3d formats I must resort to points and triangles.
Can anyone suggest a different approach?

Comment: what were you expecting the process to do with a group of points?

Comment: My expectation was that it was able to reproduce the outline of the country by taking into account the inside and the ouside of a shape.

Comment: It doesn't produce an incorrect result. Actually, it works as it should. As the next step, you can clip triangulation result by Simplified layer. Or using "Select by location" you can select triangles within the Simplified layer and then Extract them.

Comment: Ok but it seems a bit clunky. My objective is to convert this data into a 3d mesh, I don't see an option to export into collada or similar formats so I have to resort to points and triangulation. Any suggestion to streamline the process?

Comment: Can you please edit your question to ask what you actually want to do, maybe we can be more helpful then

Comment: Edited after the comments.

Comment: Do you think that an STL format file would be enough to achieve your goal? There is [DEMto3D plugin](https://demto3d.com/en/) to export the DEM generated by the interpolation.

Comment: Are you referring to the interpolation plugin or something else builtin?